Determine all pairs $(x, y)$ of integers that satisfy the equation $(x + 1)^{4} − (x − 1)^{4} = y^{3}$, using the "squeeze principle" (inequalities)
Obviously the pair $(0, 0)$ works.
Then I tried to expand the LHS, ending up with $$8x^3+8x=8x(x^2+1)=y^3$$
From here, i said that, with $z$ an integer, $$x^2+1=x^{2+3z}$$ because we need a factor that makes $x$ a cube. Therefore, manipulating and factoring x^{2}, $$x^{2}(x^{3z}-1)=1$$ therefore $$x^{3z}=2$$ is impossible for every integer $x, z$.
Is it enough to demonstrate that there are no pairs $(x, y)$ of integers that satisfy the equation other than $(0, 0)$?
If yes, is there a way of solving this with inequalities?
Thanks, Thomas :)

I don't understand your equation $x^2+1=x^{2+3z}$.  Why should $x^2+1$ be a power of $x$ at all?

I was gonna point out to the same issue @lulu did. For $x(x^2+1)$ to be a perfect square, it is not always the case that $x^2+1$ has that form. For example, $x$ itself can be a perfect cube.

There is a way to solve this with inequalities. The key observation is $8x^3+8x$ is very close to $(2x)^3$, so $y$ has to be very close to $2x$ (but can't be $2x$ exactly for $x\neq 0$).

Hint for first method: Notice that $x$ and $x^2+1$ are always relatively prime. Then think about how the product of them can be a perfect cube.

Hint for second method: Are you familiar with "squeeze principle" for Diophantine equations?

This question is similar to: Diophantine Equation Without Using Fermat's Last Theorem. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Found using an Approach0 search. There are also several AoPS threads, e.g., ...

(cont.) Diophantine equation and Hard Diophantine Equations, that contain a variety of approaches (although a quick glance indicates that some of them are not completely correct). Finally, welcome to Math SE.

@lulu I had those intuitions but went the wrong way to prove them, thanks. Also, Zoe Allen that's exactly the inequality method I was searching for.

@JohnOmielan I find this website very helpful. I will surely use it often. Thanks for the links to AoPS

Thanks to @lulu for providing the baseline for this answer.
First, we expand the left side of the equation as you did.
$$8x(x^2+1)=y^3$$
So,
$$x(x^2+1)=(y/2)^3$$
Because $x^2$ has all of the factors of $x$, $x^2+1$ has none.  Thus, since
$$x(x^2+1)=(y/2)^3$$
$x(x^2+1)$ must be either a perfect cube or a perfect cube divided by 8 (in the case where $y$ is odd).  This actually doesn't matter, because if $y$ was odd and $x^2+1$ was a perfect cube divided by 8, $x^2+1$ would not be an integer, thus we do not have to worry about this case.  Since $x$ and $x^2+1$ share no common factors, they must both be perfect cubes as well.  This is impossible except when $x=0$ or $x=-1$ because if $x$ is a perfect cube, $x^2$ will be as well, and thus $x^2+1$ won't be unless $x=0$ because the difference between them is 1, thus, they must be consecutive cubes, and the difference between two consecutive cubes $x^3$ and $(x+1)^3$ is $3x^2+3x+1$.  Since we are aiming for one, we want to satisfy $3x^2+3x+1=1$.
We cancel the ones and divide by three; thus:
$$x^2+x=0$$
The only solutions to this are $0$ and $-1$; however, there is no solution of $y$ for  $x=-1$.  Therefore, the only solution is $x=0$ and its respective solution for $y$.  Thus, $x=0$ and $y=0$ is the only solution.

I lost you after the first 'Thus'. Where does the sign change come from? Why either a perfect cube or a perfect cube divided by $2$? Why not finish immediately by noting that $x$ and $x^2+1$ are perfect cubes? This shows that $|x|\leq1$ and so you are done.
